# This error has occurred while trying to insert few records. Please explain what are the steps need to be done to eliminate this error

Tags: apex, trigger

During the load of Company Portfolio object we encountered the below error and 1313 records failed.

Error Message:

Class.CompanyPortfolioUtilityClass.assignCTMtoPortfolio: line 77  column 1                  
Trigger.CompanyPortFolioTrigger_After: line 17 column 1]
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION Team Member already exists:

Answer (score 0):

I would assume, that a trigger tries to create "Team Members" for a related account of the inserted object (maybe the standard object? You should be able to find that out. We have no way of knowing that). However, there is either a validation rule or (more probably) an apex validation (`addError`) in place, that prevents duplicates. This causes the trigger to fail.

A good place to start your investigation would be the `assignCTMtoPortfolio` method in `CompanyPortfolioUtilityClass`.